# cannot create a zip with a pdf C#/ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, zip

I am grabbing my data from the database, converting it, trying to zip it up and return it to the user. I can create a zip file successfully for both txt and docx files, but if I try to use a pdf or zip file it fails and says file cannot be downloaded. Any ideas on where the code is breaking down when trying to create a zip from a pdf?

```
if (e.CommandName == "DownloadAttachment")
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
        var item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        fileId = (int)item.GetDataKeyValue("Unique");
        FileData[] allrecords = null;
        using (
            SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PtcDbModelEntities"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select Unique1, BinaryData, FileName from PtcDbTracker.dbo.CafFileTable where Unique1=@fileId AND FileName IS NOT NULL", conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fileId", fileId));
                conn.Open();
                using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var list = new List<FileData>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        long len = reader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, 0);
                        Byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                        list.Add(new FileData { BinaryData = buffer, FileName = reader.GetString(2) });
                        allrecords = list.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
            {
                if (allrecords != null)
                {
                    foreach (var record in allrecords)
                    {
                        if (record.FileName != null)
                        {
                            ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(record.FileName, CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                            {
                                zipEntryStream.Write(record.BinaryData, 0, record.BinaryData.Length);
                                zipEntryStream.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                zipArchive.Dispose();
            }
            compressedFileStream.Close();
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.BufferOutput = true;
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "Application/zip");
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=result.zip");
            response.BinaryWrite(compressedFileStream.ToArray());
            response.Flush();
            response.SuppressContent = true;
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part of the code gives you the " file cannot be downloaded" message ? The data access , the zipping part ? the sending to stream part ?  Also , the code could benefit from being broken into smaller methods.A

Comment: @Alex The code itself is not giving me the error. Like I said, it works perfectly as long as the attached file/files is a text or docx file. Only if I try to do the same and attach a pdf file to it, when I try to then download it again (open/save prompt from the appendheader content-disposition) the prompt I receive back is that the file could not be downloaded.

Comment: do you have access to the server machine , can you attach debugger , does the code do any error logging , do you see anything in network monitor in the browser ? (F12) can you download pdf files form other sources ? have you tried different browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the specific length in the copyto overload fixed the issue.
    ...
    using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
        {
        originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream, record.BinaryData.Length);
                                        zipEntryStream.Close();
        }